# Удалить ссылку из js

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, можно ли из этого кода http://cdn.wibiya.com/Toolbars/dir_1076/Toolbar_1076068/Loader_1076068.js удалить ссылку на http://www.wibiya.com . Я в этом не силен, но как не пытался удалять - все равно ссылка восстанавливалась. Там в это js еще вложены скрипты, и не пойму откуда идет именно эта ссылка.

**UPD** В общем это тулбар, и я как понимаю он состоит не из одного js, а из нескольких, которые прописаны внутри этого http://cdn.wibiya.com/Toolbars/dir_1076/Toolbar_1076068/Loader_1076068.js Можно ли в этот тулбар вносить изменения? Например удалить кое какие элементы, а какие то добавить (различные ссылки)

Comment: Вопрос не ясен, попробуйте иначе объяснить.

Comment: **`>_< комментарии пишем в комментариях`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можете. Если осилите код. То что вы скинули - не код тулбара.
[Вот код](http://cdn.wibiya.com/Toolbars/dir_1076/Toolbar_1076068/toolbar_1082596_4eefc42ae88b7.js) который вам нужен. Вот кусок кода, который вам надо переписать

`wibiyaToolbar.framework.LinkDataReplace = function (link, withData) {
    link = link.replace(/Wibiya_TBID/g, wibiyaToolbar.id);
    link = link.replace(/Wibiya_PAGETITLE/g, encodeURIComponent(document.title));
    link = link.replace(/Wibiya_URLesc/g, escape(window.location.href));
    link = link.replace(/Wibiya_URL/g, window.location.href);
    if (withData) {
        link = link.replace(/Wibiya_SITENAME/g, wibiyaToolbar.Data.SiteName);
        link = link.replace(/Wibiya_SITEURL/g, wibiyaToolbar.Data.SiteUrl);
    }
    return link;
};`
Дальше помогать не буду ибо базис.
**UPD** Да вносить изменения можете. Но сможете ли? А это уже другой вопрос. К тому же универсальные штуки они такие. Зачем вам лишнее? Лучше своё.

Comment: Благодарю :)

Comment: Там есть кнопочка - принять или хотя бы палец вверх :)